# ember.js - how to apply action to entire {{#view}}

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to specify my action (and 'target' and 'on') in the {{#view}} instead of as below on a  contained within

```
{{#view App.Views.List
        contentBinding="this"
        classNames="item"
        classNameBindings="content.type content.selected:selected"
}}
<div {{action "select"}}>text</div>
{{/view}}
```

So that the click applied to the whole area of the App.Views.List instance. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just defining the method `click` straight on the View instead of using an `{{action}}`?

```js
App.Views.List = Ember.View.extend({
    click: function() {
        alert('clicked');
    }
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MSch/a56ke/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I deliberately wasn't using that because the event object passed to the click function had a DOMWindow object instead of a view class as event.view but it now occurs to me that is just the same as 'this' in the click function. Silly me!